# Нужен ресурс, на котором описаны алгоритмы работы с экземплярами класса c#

Tags: c#, классы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```cs
     class Student
    {
        private string name;
        private string lastname;
        private int age;
        private int course;

        public Student(string a, string b, int c, int d)
        {
            this.name = a;
            this.lastname = b;
            this.age = c;
            this.course = d;
        }
    }
```

С методом вывода информации я разобрался. Теперь вопрос, где лежит список экземпляров класса, для последующей работы с ними?
 В идеале скиньте ресурс, где я смогу это прочитать.

Comment: `где лежит список экземпляров класса` --> `var students = new List<Student>();`?

Comment: `Теперь вопрос, где лежит список экземпляров класса, для последующей работы с ними?` В списке который вы создаете. Вы как храните данные по студентам?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашёл схожий вопрос на англоязычном Stackoverflow, решение рабочее, если знаете английский - может пригодится.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18096226/c-sharp-class-object-filtering